# PHP Site and NodeJS Websocket Application behind the same Nginx server/config

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, websocket

I have a development server that is running Nginx and serving a PHP website.
Below is the working nginx config.

`cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This works perfectly to serve the PHP site; however, I would also like Nginx to run a Node based websockets server.

What changes do I need to make to this Nginx config to receive websockets traffic as well?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new file at:

`vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/somesite.com`

and put this in it:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  somesite.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/websocket.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}
```

This seems to work.